# IIS 6 Manage Users Page

Tags: iis-6

I'm trying to add a user in Manage Users page in IIS 6, somehow I have a hard time navigating or how to get there like the last time. As what I remember we went into an asp web config page not the file, there's Security then Manage Users. Hope someone could guide me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer, it's the ASP.NET WAT, clicking the config icon in visual studio brought me to the url something like this: http://localhost:portNumber/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=pathToApplication